# amd64 MOV instruction not copying properly

Tags: assembly, x86-64, yasm

There's something weird going on I don't understand.

I have a data variable:

```
variable_a dq 0
```

I check it's 0:

```
(gdb) x variable_a 
0x0:    Cannot access memory at address 0x0
```

So far so good.

I have rax:

```
(gdb) i r
rax            0x7fffffffe9e2   140737488349666
```

I MOV rax into variable.

```
mov [variable_a], rax
```

I print variable.

```
(gdb) x variable_a 
0xffffffffffffe9e2:     <error: Cannot access memory at address 0xffffffffffffe9e2>
```

Why is this happening? It looks like 1/4 of the variable is getting set to 1s when it should be 0s.

I changed to using a BSS variable and it works just fine.
I'm using YASM.

Comment: What version of yasm are you using? Only half of rax's value is being moved to variable_a...

Comment: @Rafael yasm 1.3.0

Comment: `x` expects an address. Use `x &variable_a` or `p variable_a`.

Comment: as for the sign extension, probably GDB is making a pointer from the lower 32 bits of `variable_a`. I don't think GDB has a way of knowing how actually big the variable is, so it's guessing/defaulting to 4-bytes.

Comment: @MargaretBloom x &directory_path gives 0xffffe9e2. But x/1g &directory_path gives the right value (140737488349666). Something else must be messing with variable_a then, cause the value is wrong later on. Comes out as 0x00007fffffff0000.

Comment: @nemasu Possibly, just make sure to use the correct GDB commands in order to avoid the common pitfalls. `mov [variable_a], rax` will move 64 bits, so that's not the problem. Luckily GDB is a debugger, so you can easily pinpoint what's wrong :)